# setting the div style (child component) in a card (parent component) vue3 & vuetify

Tags: javascript, css, vuejs3, nuxtjs3, vuetifyjs3

I'm new here and new with vue. so I hope to explain my self well and be understood.
Im building a gradient generator with vue3 and vuetify.
I have a child component that have a div that display a gradient color by selecting colors.
after getting the gradient that we want, I have a set button that supposed to set the preview style on a card that live in the parent component.
I'm using emit for that. This is not going well. the card get only the linear gradient but not the radial. I need that no metter what is the style on the div, the same style will be set on the card.  of course, I'm doing something wrong but I can't figur it out what else to do. I'll apriciate any help. thanks

**Child component**

```
 <!-- Displays The Final Gradient Color -->

    <v-col cols="12" md="3">
      <div align="center">Preview</div>
      <v-row>
        <v-col cols="12" col="12">
          <div
            class="d-inline-block gradientBox mt-4"
            :style="{
              background: isRadial ? radial() : gradientDirection(deg),
            }"
            :class="gradientClass"
          ></div>
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
      <v-row>
        <v-col cols="6">
          <v-btn variant="text" @click="rotate">rotate</v-btn></v-col
        >
        <v-col cols="6">
          <v-btn variant="text" @click="radial">radial</v-btn>
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
      <v-col align="center">
        <v-btn
          @click="$emit('setGradient', gradientDirection(deg), radial())"
          >set</v-btn
        >
      </v-col>
    </v-col>

<script setup lang="ts">
import type { Ref } from "vue";

const colors: Ref<{ id: number; hex: string }[]> = ref([]);
const id = ref(3);
const colorIndex: Ref<number> = ref(0);
const isRadial = ref(false);
let deg = ref(0);

const gradientClass = computed(() => {
  background: isRadial.value ? radial() : gradientDirection(deg.value);
});

colors.value.push({ id: 1, hex: "#1B9CFC" }, { id: 2, hex: "#55E6C1" });

const getColor = (ind: number) => {
  colorIndex.value = ind;
};

const up = (index: number) => {
  if (index > 0) {
    let temp = colors.value[index];
    colors.value[index] = colors.value[index - 1];
    colors.value[index - 1] = temp;
  }
};

const down = (index: number) => {
  if (index < colors.value.length - 1) {
    let temp = colors.value[index];
    colors.value[index] = colors.value[index + 1];
    colors.value[index + 1] = temp;
  }
};

const randomHex = () => {
  return "#" + Math.random().toString(16).slice(2, 8);
};

const addColor = () => {
  colors.value.push({ id: id.value, hex: randomHex() });
  id.value++;
};

const removeColor = (index: number) => {
  const filteredColors = [...colors.value];
  filteredColors.splice(index, 1);
  colors.value = filteredColors;
};

const gradientDirection = (deg: number) => {
  let gradientColor = "linear-gradient(" + deg + "deg";
  colors.value.forEach((e) => (gradientColor += "," + e.hex));
  gradientColor += ")";
  return gradientColor;
};

const rotate = () => {
  isRadial.value = false;
  deg.value += 45;
};

const radial = () => {
  isRadial.value = true;
  let radialColor = "radial-gradient( circle at center";
  colors.value.forEach((e) => (radialColor += "," + e.hex));
  radialColor += ")";
  return radialColor;
};

const emit = defineEmits<{
  (e: "setGradient", selectedGradientColor: string, radialColor: string): void;
}>();

</script>
```

**Parent component**

```
 <!-- gradient/Gradient -->
        <v-row>
          <v-col cols="12" sm="12" md="2">
            <v-btn
              flat
              class="ma-5"
              :menu="menu"
              style="background: linear-gradient(#e66465, #9198e5)"
            >
              Gradient
              <v-menu activator="parent" :close-on-content-click="false">
                <gradient-colors
                  :color="colors.gradient"
                  @set-gradient="setColor"
                ></gradient-colors>
              </v-menu>
            </v-btn>
          </v-col>
          <v-col cols="12" sm="12" md="10">
            <v-card
              :style="{
                background: selectedGradient,
              }"
              block
              class="set-gradient mt-5"
              title="gradient"
              subtitle="This is a subtitle"
              text="This is content"
            ></v-card>
          </v-col>
        </v-row>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { useTheme } from "vuetify";
import GradientColors from "./GradientColors.vue";

const theme = useTheme();
const colors = ref(theme.global.current.value.colors);
let selectedGradient = ref();

const props = defineProps({
  menu: { type: Boolean, default: false },
});

const toggleTheme = () =>
  (theme.global.name.value = theme.global.current.value.dark
    ? "myCustomLightTheme"
    : "dark");

const refreshPage = () => {
  window.location.reload();
};

const setColor = (selectedGradientColor: string, radialColor: string) => {
  selectedGradient.value = selectedGradientColor;

  console.log(selectedGradientColor);
  console.log(radialColor);
};
</script>
```

Comment: Did you actually forget to describe what is problem?

Comment: Sorry, I gusse I deleted it by mistake and haven't notice. I edited it. Thank you for paying attention

Comment: I succeeded! I used ref() for catchind the div and catch the style div. that I set to the card and it work fine.
const myDiv = ref();  
const selectedGradientColor = () => {
  return myDiv.value?.style.background;
};